# PHP: Prevent values from showing beside checkbox when retrieving from database

Tags: php

I am storing to and retrieving checkbox values from database (1s and 0s). It's working fine but how do I prevent the values from showing beside the checkbox when retrieving them? Thanks.

[screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj3Df.png)

I am retrieving the values from the database with a code like this:

```
if($firstVal != 0){
    $output .= '
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" data-id1="'.$row["checkid"].'" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="1" checked="checked">'.$row["firstrating"].'</td>
    ';
  } else {
    $output .= '
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" data-id1="'.$row["checkid"].'" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="1">'.$row["firstrating"].'</td>
    ';
  }
```

Comment: Remove `'.$row["firstrating"].'`, which I assume is that value?

Comment: just remove $row["firstrating"] this variable. thats it

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine now after removing $row["firstrating"] .

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to remove the:
'.$row["firstrating"].' after the input

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine now after removing $row["firstrating"] .

Answer (score 0):

use **`if else`** short hand as follows

```
$output .= '<td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" data-id1="'.$row["checkid"].'"name="chk1" id="chk1" value="1" <?= ($firstVal != 0) ? "checked" : "";?>>'.$row["firstrating"].'</td>';
```